# How to read dynamic url from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a .json file (see below) with image URL containing variables like the path and the project name.

```
{"imgs":[
{
 "gatewayImg": "resrcPath+_global_PROJECT_NAME+'/images/gateway-'+_global_PROJECT_NAME+'.png'"
}
]}
```

I also have my ajax request loading the file and on my request success I assign the attribute src and the source path to the image.

```
  $.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: "GET",
     global: false,
     dataType: "json",
     url: resrcPath+"imgRes.json",
     success: function (data) {
      var src = data.imgs[0].gatewayImg;
      $('.gatewayImg').attr('src', src);
     }
 });
```

The problem is that when the I do this, the image isn't found on the local server and I get this `localhost:8080/order/resrcPath+_global_PROJECT_NAME+'/images/gateway-'+_global_PROJECT_NAME+'.png'` as the src.

But when I attribute the src as followed: `$('.gatewayImg').attr('src', resrcPath+_global_PROJECT_NAME+'/images/gateway-'+_global_PROJECT_NAME+'.png');` the image shows up and the variables are well replaced by their correct value.

I don't know if my JSON is valid or not that way, and I need to know how to assign the src with the json value instead of writing the URL in the attribute function.

Comment: The variables in image are clearly not replaced since they are showing up in your source,  do a string replace to take care of these variables - or even better just compile the full URL in the JSON.

Comment: I need these variables because the URL so that the image will be changing depending on them,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is valid, but you have a string that needs to be executed (evaluated). If you have 100% control over the JSON file, you can eval the string, that assumes you have `resrcPath,_global_PROJECT_NAME` as globals.

```
 var resrcPath = "/";
 var _global_PROJECT_NAME = "global"
 eval("resrcPath+_global_PROJECT_NAME+'/images/gateway-'+_global_PROJECT_NAME+'.png'") 
    === "/global/images/gateway-global.png"


  $.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: "GET",
     global: false,
     dataType: "json",
     url: resrcPath+"imgRes.json",
     success: function (data) {
      var src = data.imgs[0].gatewayImg;
      $('.gatewayImg').attr('src', eval(src));
     }
 });
```

The best solution would be to process the string on the server so you don't need to evaluate it again on the client and open holes in your program.